# what is the difference betweent Task.Run and System.Threading.ThreadPool.RunAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, uwp

what is the effect difference of them on threading? 
the `Task.Run` seems still run on the same task manger of current threading, and `ThreadPool.RunAsync` seems more related less with current threading.

I notice that the `Task.Run` is easy to automatically capture parameter which is outside it. Such as If the `Task.Run` call a string object outside it, the `Task.Run` can automatically capture it.

Comment: There's some info here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9c18a978-4a87-40e2-9294-1346bcd2d528/difference-between-task-and-threadpool

Answer (score 2):

In general, `Task` is an abstraction over threads. The main benefit of tasks is that they allow you to focus less on the low-level aspects of multi-threading and simplify things like continuation. They are also very well integrated into C# and are the basis of modern asynchronous programming. UWP API relies on async/await quite heavily, so using `Tasks` is quite encouraged (although the UWP API itself uses `IAsyncOperation` for many of its methods as a `Task`-like type, which is Windows Runtime compatible and can be exposed in WinRT libraries).

The implementation of tasks uses the thread pool under the hood, so in general, unless you need the low-level control, `Tasks` should be easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9c18a978-4a87-40e2-9294-1346bcd2d528/difference-between-task-and-threadpool. thanks @aage. In general, when you're using managed code, you'll want to use Task.Run as it targets the CLR thread pool.  ThreadPool.RunAsync runs in native code and targets the Windows thread pool.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9c18a978-4a87-40e2-9294-1346bcd2d528/difference-between-task-and-threadpool